# Internal Cloudpages (only for SFMC Users)

Tags: marketing-cloud, login, cloudpage

I was wondering if there is a fast way to create cloud pages only for logged in SFMC users. Or create a small Log-In process that only gives users access to certain pages that have a valid token or sth.

My idea is something like an **interactive way** to display total sends per chooseable period of time, seperating those numbers into country statistics and bounce analysis or by jobid and so on which should not be publically available.

- Has anybody done something like this before?
- Would you approach a different way (like not trying to use cloudpages for that but an internal website and use API calls instead of direct AMPScript/SSJS)?

Comment: What you need is a micro site

Comment: Microsites are only for internals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has unfortunately been sunset as a capability.  The only place that you could easily insert security to only allow SFMC users was inside of the Microsite feature.  This unfortunately is part of 'Classic' and will sunset in January 2019.

There has been interest from many users on attempting to bring this capability into CloudPages, but the reception from SFMC seems to be that it either won't happen or is so low on their 'To Do' list, that it will be a long while before it becomes available.

That being said, it is not impossible to secure your CloudPage, but it would require a completely custom build and likely will be a significant project - likely putting cost above benefit.  If you already have a secure environment inside your company, your best bet is to create the page behind there and then use API calls to gather the information.

Comment: You can build micro sites in cloud pages?

Comment: Yes, but not the same as the Microsite feature inside classic. This was what was used prior to CloudPages