# Cloud page user authentication

Tags: cloudpage

For one of our cloud pages, we would need to add an authentication layer. 
Can the security feature available for microsites or somethign similar be applied to cloud pages?

*You can enforce security on your landing page by requiring users to log in to see it. Currently, the system can validate that the users have a valid Salesforce Marketing Cloud account and password.*
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/

Comment: @Rain i dont understand your question

Comment: Questions on SE are about a specific problem, and you have not detailed out what have you tried to build this authentication model. Take a look at How To Ask - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rain updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately by default there are no additional security settings as such that could be applied to CloudPages, meaning any authentication logic on top needs to be custom built with AMPscript/SSJS.

On how to set it up for Cloud Pages you can check what has been recommended to others in [**Login Page Validation via AMPScript**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241306/login-page-validation-amp-script) and [**Internal CloudPage for SFMC Users**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231561/internal-cloudpages-only-for-sfmc-users).

Essentially until Salesforce decides to re-introduce Microsite features to Cloud Pages ([**not happening in January 2019 release**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2019_platform.htm&type=5)) the only way is to create a fully custom solution.